# Using several independent instances of Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

As many people, I too have several email accounts. Until now, I have been using `Thunderbird` for my main account, and either used web interface for the other accounts, or used other email clients (`Sylpheed`, `Balsa`, ...). For some reason, I never liked the idea of having separate, independent accounts integrated in one email client, perhaps because the added complexity and possibility of confusion. When I used three different email clients, I had three truly independent email accounts.

The only disadvantage is, the other (non-Thunderbird) email clients never worked as well as Thunderbird.

Now I am wondering whether there is a possibility to use three independent instances of `Thunderbird`, so that I don't have to use inferior email clients.

I know that when `Thunderbird` is already running, I cannot start another instance. Also, any additional instance would need its own (independent) config directory.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I am using `Thunderbird` (`Icedove 24.6.0`) on Debian Wheezy

## UPDATE:

I have found [this article on MozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Run_multiple_copies_of_Thunderbird_at_the_same_time), which suggests to use the `-no-remote` option and does not mention the option `-new-instance` at all.

The `man page` lists both options, but does not explain what the difference is, if `-new-instance` is implied when `-no-remote` is used, or whether they should both be used at the same time.

```
thunderbird -P "profile_name" -no-remote
thunderbird -P "profile_name" -new-instance
```

## Side note:

The refered article also says, that:

```
Multiple instances is intended for debugging, so use it at your own risk
```

Well, I don't intend to use it for debugging, I want to use it for my work. What can possibly go wrong when using multiple instances? How can I mitigate that danger?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can start Thunderbird from the commandline with the `-P <profile>` option to specify a different profile. Within the different profiles you have complete seperation. IIRC specifying a profile implies the `-new-instance` option when starting `thunderbird` but if not, just add it.

To create a new profile start thunderbird from the commandline with:

```
thunderbird -ProfileManager -new-instance
```

---

On the other hand, have you tried using the IMAP protocol? This gives me completely different trees of folders one for each account that I have in (one) Thunderbird session. Unless I actively copy messages from one account to the other everything stays separate and as long as you close the tree of the account your are not working on, things should not be confusing.

Comment: is it `-new-instance` with Thunderbird? the Firefox argument is `--no-remote` (and it is _not_ implied by `-P`).

Comment: @strugee I did `thunderbird --help` that gives `-new-instance      Open new instance, not a new window in running instance`. I thought it was implied, as otherwise I think you would have to switch profiles as I don't recall Thunderbird being able to handle two at a time in one session.

Comment: @Anthon - If the second profile does not exist, is there a way to create it?

Comment: @user1968963 start with `thunderbird -ProfileManager`

Comment: @Anthon - in the man page, there is also an option `-no-remote: Do not connect to a running Thunderbird instance`. What is the difference between `-new-instance` and `-no-remote`? Should I use both?

Comment: @user1968963 My thunderbird's help (`thunderbird --help`) says for `-no-remote`: `Do not accept or send remote commands; implies -new-instance.`. That makes more sense for the option name involved, thus I think your man page is incorrect.